# Kivy: AttributeError with property defined in kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, attributeerror

- **Python**: 3.6.8
- **Kivy**: 1.9.0
- **PyCharm**: 2019.2.3

I'm reading "*Kivy – Interactive Applications and Games in Python Second Edition*" while writing and testing the source code in the book.

When I was finishing chapter 3 I got to this error:

```
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.observable_list_dispatch'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 579, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (/tmp/pip-install-rsswmpdy/kivy/kivy/properties.c:7216)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/tmp/pip-install-rsswmpdy/kivy/kivy/_event.c:14036)
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/tmp/pip-install-rsswmpdy/kivy/kivy/_event.c:13194)
File "/home/madtyn/PycharmProjects/learning_kivy/comics/drawingspace.py", line 8, in on_children
    self.status_bar.counter = len(self.children)
AttributeError: 'DrawingSpace' object has no attribute 'status_bar'
```

I tried to locate the error by comparing my code with the downloaded source code from the book, but I found no relevant difference. In both versions which are almost identical, I don't appreciate any difference in the relation between status_bar and DrawingSpace.

I'm pasting my code below. I'm omitting these files:

- toolbox.*
- comicwidgets.*
- generaloptions.*

  because I think they are not relevant, so everything it's easier. But I will paste them on demand if anyone asks or this doesn't get resolved.

**comiccreator.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

Builder.load_file('toolbox.kv')
Builder.load_file('drawingspace.kv')
Builder.load_file('comicwidgets.kv')
Builder.load_file('generaloptions.kv')
Builder.load_file('statusbar.kv')


class ComicCreator(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class ComicCreatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ComicCreator()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ComicCreatorApp().run()
```

**comiccreator.kv**

```
# File name: comiccreator.kv
#:kivy 1.9.0

<ComicCreator>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ToolBox:
            id: _tool_box
            drawing_space: _drawing_space
            comic_creator: root
            size_hint: None, None
            width: 100
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        DrawingSpace:
            id: _drawing_space
            status_bar: _status_bar  # <====== Here we define the status_bar property!!!
            general_options: _general_options
            tool_box: _tool_box
            size_hint: None, None
            width: root.width - _tool_box.width
            height: root.height - _general_options.height - _status_bar.height
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            GeneralOptions:
                id: _general_options
                drawing_space: _drawing_space
                comic_creator: root
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: 48
            StatusBar:
                id: _status_bar
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: 24
```

**drawingspace.py**

```
# File name: drawingspace.py
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    def on_children(self, instance, value):
        self.status_bar.counter = len(self.children)  # Here the error states that
                                                      # status_bar attr does not exist
```

**drawingspace.kv**

```
# File name: drawingspace.kv

#:kivy 1.9.0
#:import drawingspace drawingspace

<DrawingSpace@RelativeLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Line:
            rectangle: 0, 0, self.width - 4, self.height - 4
    StickMan:
```

**statusbar.py**

```
# File name: statusbar.py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty


class StatusBar(BoxLayout):
    counter = NumericProperty(0)
    previous_counter = 0

    def on_counter(self, instance, value):
        if value == 0:
            self.msg_label.text = "Drawing space cleared"
        elif value - 1 == self.__class__.previous_counter:
            self.msg_label.text = "Widget added"
        elif value + 1 == StatusBar.previous_counter:
            self.msg_label.text = "Widget removed"
        self.__class__.previous_counter = value
```

**statusbar.kv**

```
# File name: statusbar.kv
#:kivy 1.9.0
#:import statusbar statusbar

<StatusBar@BoxLayout>:
    msg_label: _msg_label
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: 'Total Figures: ' + str(root.counter)
    Label:
        id: _msg_label
        text: "Kivy started"
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I would try adding `status_bar = ObjectProperty(None)` to your `DrawingSpace` class definition.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sorry for answering so late. Doing that throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'counter'`.

Comment: Try protecting that line in your `on_children` with `if self.status_bar is not None:`

Comment: ¡That worked! But, why the downloaded source code doesn't need that?

Comment: You can post your solution and I will accept it, but it would be nice (also for people reading this) knowing why this error happens. I don't understand yet why the status_bar is not there in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following the same book and had the same issue! After reading these responses, @JohnAnderson is correct - `DrawingSpace.on_children()` gets called before `status_bar` exists within the `DrawingSpace`.  But why?

Remember that the root widget of the app here is a `ComicCreator` as defined in `comiccreator.kv`.  If you take a look at the instance of `DrawingSpace` there, `status_bar` is defined right after its own `id`, so it would seem that there shouldn't be a problem.

But, we must remember that **kv class rules** are executed first. So looking at `drawingspace.kv`, we see that the `<DrawingSpace>` rule imports the python class (so it already knows about the `on_children` method) and then adds a `StickMan` **within the rule**.  All that happens BEFORE the INSTANCE of `DrawingSpace` gets a `status_bar` attribute added to it within the `comiccreator.kv` file.

Simply delete the `StickMan` from `drawingspace.kv` and the error will disappear.  [**Edit** the following is incorrect: If you want, you can add `StickMan` as a child of `DrawingSpace` in `comiccreator.kv` (after `status_bar` has been added) and you will visually get the same result with no error.]

Lastly, you should remove `@RelativeLayout` from `<DrawingSpace@RelativeLayout>`. Once you define a custom class in python and inherit from a base class, you no longer need to inherit from a base class in kv using the `@` operator.  See the notes on page 10 for more info on that.

Comment: I'm busy today for checking this, but I promise I will read and try it ASAP and tell you.

Comment: I'm really sorry for such a long delay. Personal circumstances. It seems you are right. Commenting the StickMan does solve the issue but adding it in comiccreator.kv, under DrawingSpace does not get to print the StickMan. I would like to get this solved in order to change the best answer and mark yours as the best.

Comment: I achieved now to add the StickMan as child of DrawingSpace in the comiccreator.kv and it prints the StickMan and runs the app but is giving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'counter'` error in the console because counter does not exist

Comment: This is being caused by the same issue. You are adding `StickMan` in `drawingspace.kv` ie in the `<DrawingSpace>` **rule**.  You need to add it under the `DrawingSpace` **instance** which is in `comiccreator.kv`, in the `<ComicCreator>` rule (as stated above). When the DS rule is executed, `DrawingSpace` is just a `RelativeLayout`, and then you're adding `StickMan` which triggers the `on_children()` method.. But it has no idea what `status_bar` is! Its `status_bar` attribute hasn't been created yet, since it is created in the **instance** (in `comiccreator.kv`, in the `<ComicCreator>` rule).

Comment: So, where should I write the `StickMan:` line if not in comiccreator.kv directly under `DrawingSpace:`? Because it should be a child of DrawingSpace, right?

Comment: Or maybe the code is wrong and I should always initialize counter or check for the status_bar to exist?

Comment: `StickMan` should go under `DrawingSpace`'s `height` attribute in `comiccreator.kv`, in the `<ComicCreator>` rule. The code is not wrong so you should leave it as is. As you build your own apps, it will be important to understand what's going on here with the execution order... I would not suggest putting checks in place that aren't needed - it will only confuse you more in the long run.  You may want to read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58591221/kivy-attribute-error-object-has-no-attribute-trying-to-connect-widgets-in-kv) that @JohnAnderson helped me with.

Comment: Same error. I swear. I did as you told me: https://i.postimg.cc/tTNZkK1H/image.png

Comment: Looks like you updated `comiccreator.kv` correctly.  In `drawingspace.kv`, make sure to remove `StickMan`.  Also remove the `@RelativeLayout` from `<DrawingSpace@RelativeLayout>`.  If that still produces an error, update your post with the other files and I will try and figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I think everything is in there: https://github.com/madtyn/learningkivy/tree/master/comics

Comment: My bad, I stand corrected. I'm getting the same error, I guess because `StatusBar` is instantiated lower down in `comiccreator.kv`? My original answer still applies, just not the part about adding `StickMan` to `DrawingSpace` with no errors. I will update my answer to delete that sentence. In any case, if you're following the book, we're not supposed to create `DrawingSpace` with any `StickMan` in there, its supposed to be blank.. so just delete it entirely and you won't have any errors and you'll be on pace with the book.

Comment: Ok, I must have gotten wrong in the way. I will do as you say and then review all the steps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, I'm accepting your answer. I'm telling you just in case you want to edit anything for other readers

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what is happening is that your `on_children()` method of `DrawingSpace` is being called before the `status_bar` property is set. Since the `on_children()` method is called whenever the `children` of `DrawingSpace` changes, you can protect the reference to `status_bar` by adding a check of whether it is set:

```
class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    def on_children(self, instance, value):
        if self.status_bar is not None:
            self.status_bar.counter = len(self.children)
```

As to why your code needs this and the code in your book doesn't - I cannot guess, since I don't have that book.

Answer (score 1):

Defining properties in kv can introduce parse order issues when things depend on them, as you've found. The best solution is probably to only use dynamically created properties for simple things, and otherwise just define the properties normally in the class definition.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I'm still reading the book and I wouldn't know how to define properly the property. Also, the source code from the book doesn't seem to do anything outside the kv file as well.