# Kivy Attribute Error - object has no attribute - Trying to connect widgets in kv language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I seem to be having nonstop problems with trying to connect widgets in Kivy.  I've read [this useful guide](http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/) but my situation isn't directly covered.

I have 2 different "choosers" side by side like this: [image: KeySigChooser test]

Each chooser will be its own class, held by the KeySigChooserContainer. I want to size the buttons based on the size of the KeySigChooserContainer, so that the buttons will have consistent sizes.  This is accomplished with

```
ChooserButton:
    ...
    width: root.parent.width * (3/32)
```

but I don't like using the `parent` reference; I'd much rather use a direct reference for flexibility as the app grows in complexity.  But when I try doing that with

```
<RootNoteChooser>:
    ...
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        ChooserButton:
            ...
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)

<ModeChooser>:
    ...
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        ChooserButton:
            ...
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)

<KeySigChooserContainer>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        RootNoteChooser:
            box: box
        ModeChooser:
            box: box
```

I get an attribute error: `AttributeError: 'RootNoteChooser' object has no attribute 'box'`

I've used a similar technique elsewhere in my project so I have no idea why this isn't working.  I have also tried making `box` an ObjectProperty within the RootNoteChooser and ModeChooser classes but that doesn't work.

```
# keysigchooser.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

chrom_scale = ['C', 'C#/Db', 'D', 'D#/Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#/Gb', 'G', 'G#/Ab', 'A', 'A#/Bb', 'B']
chrom_scale2 = ['C', 'C/D', 'D', 'D/E', 'E', 'F', 'F/G', 'G', 'G/A', 'A', 'A/B', 'B']


class ModeChooser(FloatLayout):
    pass


class RootNoteChooser(FloatLayout):
    note_idx = NumericProperty(0)

    def increment_note_idx(self):
        self.note_idx = (self.note_idx + 1) % 12

    def decrement_note_idx(self):
        self.note_idx = (self.note_idx - 1) % 12

    def on_note_idx(self, instance, value):
        self.note_text.text = chrom_scale[self.note_idx]


class KeySigChooserContainer(FloatLayout):
    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        target_ratio = 60/20
        width, height = self.size
        # check which size is the limiting factor
        if width / height > target_ratio:
            # window is "wider" than targeted, so the limitation is the height.
            self.ids.box.height = height
            self.ids.box.width = height * target_ratio
        else:
            self.ids.box.width = width
            self.ids.box.height = width / target_ratio


class KeySigChooserApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KeySigChooserContainer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KeySigChooserApp().run()
```

```
# keysigchooser.kv
<ChooserButton@Button>:
    font_name: "Arial"
    font_size: self.width
    border: [2, 2, 2, 2]


<RootNoteChooser>:
    note_text: note_text
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25C4'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.increment_note_idx()
        Label:
            id: note_text
            text: "C"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25BA'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.decrement_note_idx()


<ModeChooser>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25C4'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)
        Label:
            text: "Major"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25BA'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)


<KeySigChooserContainer>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        size_hint: [None, None]
        orientation: "horizontal"
        RootNoteChooser:
            id: rootnotechooser
            box: box
            size_hint: [0.4, 1]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1, 0, 0, 0.5]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        ModeChooser:
            id: modechooser
            box: box
            size_hint: [0.6, 1]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0, 1, 0, 0.5]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Clearly I'm missing something here... any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This seems to be one of those situations where there's not a *great* way to solve the problem. Thanks to @JohnAnderson, here's what I learned:

1. [An id is limited in scope to the rule it is declared in.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html)
2. [the outermost widget applies the kv rules to all its inner widgets before any other rules are applied](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html?highlight=lang)
3. Rules are always applied **before** instances.

The problem here is I am using an attribute (`box`) in the `<RootNoteChooser>` and `<ModeChooser>` **rules**, but that attribute gets created in the **instance** of `RootNoteChooser` and `ModeChooser`.  Since rules are applied first, `box` does not yet exist.

The work-around I'm using for this is to also create the `box` attribute in both rules, and set it to something that makes sense (and won't cause an error). Then, in the `RootNoteChooser` and `ModeChooser` instances (in the `<KeySigChooser>` rule), `box` will get reset to the proper object.  Here's the gist of it:

```
<RootNoteChooser>:
    box: self.parent  # Initially we'll set it to something reasonable.
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        ChooserButton:
            ...
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)

<ModeChooser>:
    box: self.parent  # Initially we'll set it to something reasonable.
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        ChooserButton:
            ...
            width: root.box.width * (3/32)

<KeySigChooserContainer>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        RootNoteChooser:
            box: box  # Now box attribute is correct, and can be pointed at any
        ModeChooser:
            box: box  # id that is within this rule.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you must watch when setting up references to properties in kivy is when those properties will be available. Your original code seems reasonable, but the problem is that the `box` property of `RootNoteChooser` and `ModeChooser` is accessed before it is set-up. You can get around that by defining a property that can be used before its value is actually set. In this case, using a `NumericProperty(0)` will allow your code to use the initial value of zero, even though that is not the correct value. Then when the correct value is assigned (by Kivy), it will work as you expect. Here is a modified version of your code using that approach:

```
# keysigchooser.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

chrom_scale = ['C', 'C#/Db', 'D', 'D#/Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#/Gb', 'G', 'G#/Ab', 'A', 'A#/Bb', 'B']
chrom_scale2 = ['C', 'C/D', 'D', 'D/E', 'E', 'F', 'F/G', 'G', 'G/A', 'A', 'A/B', 'B']


class ModeChooser(FloatLayout):
    box_width = NumericProperty(0)   # starts off as zero, just so there is  number available


class RootNoteChooser(FloatLayout):
    box_width = NumericProperty(0)   # starts off as zero, just so there is  number available
    note_idx = NumericProperty(0)

    def increment_note_idx(self):
        self.note_idx = (self.note_idx + 1) % 12

    def decrement_note_idx(self):
        self.note_idx = (self.note_idx - 1) % 12

    def on_note_idx(self, instance, value):
        self.note_text.text = chrom_scale[self.note_idx]


class KeySigChooserContainer(FloatLayout):
    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        target_ratio = 60/20
        width, height = self.size
        # check which size is the limiting factor
        if width / height > target_ratio:
            # window is "wider" than targeted, so the limitation is the height.
            self.ids.box.height = height
            self.ids.box.width = height * target_ratio
        else:
            self.ids.box.width = width
            self.ids.box.height = width / target_ratio

Builder.load_string('''
# keysigchooser.kv
<ChooserButton@Button>:
    font_name: "Arial"
    font_size: self.width
    border: [2, 2, 2, 2]


<RootNoteChooser>:
    note_text: note_text
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25C4'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box_width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.increment_note_idx()
        Label:
            id: note_text
            text: "C"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25BA'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box_width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.decrement_note_idx()


<ModeChooser>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25C4'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box_width * (3/32)
        Label:
            text: "Major"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25BA'
            size_hint: [None, 1]
            width: root.box_width * (3/32)


<KeySigChooserContainer>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        size_hint: [None, None]
        orientation: "horizontal"
        RootNoteChooser:
            id: rootnotechooser
            box_width: box.width   # this sets the box_width
            size_hint: [0.4, 1]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1, 0, 0, 0.5]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        ModeChooser:
            id: modechooser
            box_width: box.width   # this sets the box_width
            size_hint: [0.6, 1]
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0, 1, 0, 0.5]
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
''')
class KeySigChooserApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KeySigChooserContainer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KeySigChooserApp().run()
```

I put your `keysigchooser.kv` into a `Builder.load_string()` call just for my own convenience.

There are numerous ways to accomplish what you want. Another way is to set the `ChooserButton` sizes using your `on_size()` method of  `KeySigChooserContainer`. To do this, add ids to the `ChooserButtons` and add the following code to the end of that method:

```
    # set button sizes
    self.ids.rootnotechooser.ids.butt1.width = self.ids.box.width * 3/32
    self.ids.rootnotechooser.ids.butt2.width = self.ids.box.width * 3/32
    self.ids.modechooser.ids.butt1.width = self.ids.box.width * 3/32
    self.ids.modechooser.ids.butt2.width = self.ids.box.width * 3/32
```

And yet another method is to remove the `<RootNoteChooser>` and `<ModeChooser>` rules from your `kv` file and place the contents of those rules directly under the `ModeChooser` and `RootNoteChooser` sections of the  `<KeySigChooserContainer>` rule. This would allow you to set the `ChooserButton` widths using:

```
width: box.width * (3/32)
```

similar to your original code.

Comment: I see that this works but IMHO it feels like more of a work-around than an answer. Is this the **right** way of doing this? It seems like bad practice to create a property (`box_width`) that already exists (`box.width`). Using `root.parent.width` works, so clearly the BoxLayout that holds these "choosers" exists. But it appears the <RootNoteChooser> and <ModeChooser> **rules** are executed before their respective **instance** where the attribute is created (`box: box`). Is there a better way to structure the kv file to avoid the issue? (Thank you for the time you spent writing these answers!)

Comment: In my answer above, I have added two alternative methods to accomplish what you want.

Comment: What do you think about a 4th option:  in <RootNoteChooser> and <ModeChooser> rules, set `box: self.parent` so that `box` exists. Then later when instantiated, `box` will be overwritten with whatever `id` you attach to it (I think). This allows us to still use `box.width` (instead of `box_width`), and the kv file can still be separated into rules for each class.

Comment: @marcus_afailius, I think that will work, but I think you will need to use `root.box.width` rather than `box.width`. Many different way to accomplish the same result!!

Comment: Thanks!  Using `root.box.width` is what I'm currently going with.  In my main app, `box` is actually higher in the widget tree than I explained here, so that seems to be the cleanest option. I don't particularly **like** any of these solutions though, as they all seem to be a bit hacky.. but maybe it just is what it is.  I'll let this post linger for a bit to see if any others have input, otherwise I'll update my OP and mark this as the answer.  Thanks again for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the children of the `BoxLayout` to be a certain fraction of the `BoxLayout` width, you can just use `size_hint` (that is what its intended use is). For example, in your `RootNoteChooser`:

```
<RootNoteChooser>:
    note_text: note_text
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center": [0.5, 0.5]}
        orientation: "horizontal"
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25C4'
            size_hint: [3/32, 1]
            #width: root.box.width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.increment_note_idx()
        Label:
            id: note_text
            text: "C"
            size_hint: [26/32, 1]
        ChooserButton:
            text: u'\u25BA'
            size_hint: [3/32, 1]
            #width: root.box.width * (3/32)
            on_press: root.decrement_note_idx()
```

In a `BoxLayout`, those children with `size_hint` assigned will take up that fraction of the remaining space after the other children's size is subtracted. So, in the above example, the `Label` space is subtracted from the parent `BoxLayout` and the remaining space is divided between the `ChooserButtons`. Adding a similar `size_hint` for the `Label` makes it clearer.

Comment: Right - but I want _different_ widths for the RootNoteChooser and ModeChooser and the _same_ widths for the ChooserButtons (sorry if that wasn't clear).  Whether I use `size_hint` or `width` directly, the button width needs to be based off of KeySigChooser's width, the common parent to all ChooserButtons.